# Spring Boot war packaging: Execution with additional classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I would like to package my Spring Boot application as a war package in order to

- deploy on existing tomcat
- running standalone with `java -jar application.war`

with the same artifact. To achieve this I set the scope of `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` to `provided` so these dependencies are located in folder `lib-provided`.

I don't want to include the Database driver in the artifact. When running on existing tomcat I just add the database driver (as jar) to its lib folder.

Now my question: How can I add the additional classpath (e.g. `lib/*`) to the `java -jar application.war` command? Traditional approaches (like `java -cp lib/* -jar application.war`) did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that Spring Boot uses a WarLauncher to run executable war files. So

```
 java -cp drivers/*:application.war org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher
```

is a working commandline command to add additional jar files to the classpath without modifying or unpacking the war file.